# How to detect if a char string has Hebrew characters in UTF-8?

Tags: utf-8, char, detect, hebrew

I am using C++. I need to read a UTF-8 encoding file and in this file it may have some Hebrew words. As you may know, the logic order of Hebrew words is opposite with its visual order. I want to reverse it as soon as the word is detected as a Hebrew word. Question is how can I detect if this char string has Hebrew characters?

Thanks,

Comment: This is a display issue, you're not supposed to reverse any part of the text. Where do you intend to display the text?

Comment: I want to display it in Linux desktop Icon and the application used to display the desktop icon is programmed using the C and X API.

Comment: Xlib has very limited support for text layout. Consider using Pango.

Comment: I don't want to totally rewrite the existing application. I am not familiar with Pango, and not sure how much work I need to do.

Comment: You didn't mention an existing application in the question. I would recommend posting a new question with all the details and your limitations, since this one won't get many views given it was posted in August.